# alertcondition when change color string INLINE_COL

Tags: pine-script

i have code in indicator-

```
string INLINE_COL = "Colour Pallette"
i_colUp     = input( color.teal,    "Colour Pallette  ",    input.color,    group = GROUP_CAND, inline = INLINE_COL )
i_colDown   = input( color.red,     " ",                    input.color,    group = GROUP_CAND, inline = INLINE_COL )
```

How to write clear code function for alert condition when i_colUp change on i_colDown and reverse?

i try this but this errors of compilation

```
// Track color changes
colorChanged = crossover(i_colUp, i_colDown)

// Create alert condition
if colorChanged
    alertcondition("Color has changed from (" + tostring(color.rgb(i_colUp)[0]) + "," + tostring(color.rgb(i_colUp)[1]) + "," + tostring(color.rgb(i_colUp)[2]) + ") to (" + tostring(color.rgb(i_colDown)[0]) + "," + tostring(color.rgb(i_colDown)[1]) + "," + tostring(color.rgb(i_colDown)[2]) + ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

`color` does not have a value that can "cross" another value.

The variables you are referring are input variables. You need to find the variable that sets the color of your plot/line etc. After that, you can compare the previous color with the current color.

Example:

```
plot_color = up_condition ? i_colUp : i_colDown
plot(close, color=plot_color)

is_new_up = (plot_color[1] != i_colUp) and (plot_color == i_colUp)  // Color on the previous bar was not i_colUp and color on the current bar is i_colUp

alertcondition(is_new_up, "New up color")
```

Comment: Undeclared identifier 'up_condition';
Undeclared identifier 'plot_color';
Undeclared identifier 'plot_color';
Undeclared identifier 'is_new_up'

Comment: i forgot //@version=4

Comment: That was just an example so you can understand the implementation and do it yourself.

Comment: i write full code maybe more answers because this example not working

Comment: string INLINE_COL = "Colour Pallette"
i_colUp = input( color.teal, "Colour Pallette  ", input.color, group = GROUP_CAND, inline = INLINE_COL )
i_colDown = input( color.red, " ", input.color, group = GROUP_CAND, inline = INLINE_COL )
i_colWick = input( color.gray, " ", input.color, group = GROUP_CAND, inline = INLINE_COL )

Comment: // RSI Heikin-Ashi generation function
f_rsiHeikinAshi( _length ) =>

Comment: // return the OHLC values
[ _open, _high, _low, _close ]

Comment: // get OHLC values to use in the plotcandle()
[ O, H, L, C ] = f_rsiHeikinAshi( i_lenHARSI )

Comment: // make our HA rsi candles
plotcandle( O, H, L, C, "HARSI", bodyColour, wickColour, bordercolor = bodyColour )